# Get all keys in the Codable (or Decodable)

Tags: swift

Given the following codable `struct`:

```
struct MyBanana: Codable {
    var b: String?
    var z: String?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case b = "B"
        case z = "ZOOM"
    }
}
```

How can i get an array of strings like so: `["B", "ZOOM"]` without an instance of `MyBanana`?

Additionally, is there a way to get this from auto-synthesised `CodingKeys`, e.g.

```swift
    struct MyBanana: Codable {
        var b: String?
        var z: String?
    }
```

would return `["b","z"]`

I tried the following for the first question:

```swift
func whatever<T, Key>(keyedBy: Key.Type) -> [T] where T: Codable, Key: CodingKey
{
    let allKeys: [Key] = [Key]()
    for k in keyedBy {
        allKeys.append(k)
    }
    
    return [T]()
}
```

But i get

> Type 'Key.Type' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'

**Update**

For declared `CodingKeys` @Cameron Porter's answer works fine (add `CaseIterable` to the enum)

For synthesized ones this works, albeit pretty manual still:

```
extension Decodable {
    func getAllCodingKeys(_ activator: (String) -> String) -> [String] {
        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)
        return mirror.children.filter({ $0.label != nil }).map({ activator($0.label!) })
    }
}
```

Then in your Codable, add

```
func getAllKeys() -> [String] {
        return self.getAllCodingKeys { CodingKeys(stringValue: $0)!.stringValue }
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
struct MyBanana: Codable {
  var b: String?
  var z: String?

  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey, CaseIterable {
    case b = "B"
    case z = "ZOOM"
  }

  static var allCases: [String] {
    return CodingKeys.allCases.map { $0.rawValue }
  }
}
```

And then you can get your array of coding keys as

```
MyBanana.allCases
```

Doesn't work for auto-synthesised coding keys however